# C: Pointer struction comparing doesn't work

Tags: c, struct, compare

I should compare a struction with anothter without using strcmp(). But everytime the firstName on both sides are the same it doesn't go in the if function. I know the function gets the names bc in the printf I see clearly the names.

```
typedef struct{
    char firstName[MAXC];
    char familyName[MAXC];
    char gender;
} TPerson;
....

int comparePeopleByFirstName(TPerson *a, TPerson *b){
    if(a->firstName == b->firstName){
        if(a->familyName < b->familyName){
            return 1;
        } else if (a->familyName > b->familyName){
            return -1;
        }
     }else if(a->firstName < b->firstName){
        return 1;
    } else if (a->firstName > b->firstName){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can't use `strcmp` you need to compare each character in the string. `==` on a `char *` is comparing the pointer/address and not the string characters.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, the structure contains *arrays* as members, not pointers.  Therefore, it can never be the case that `(a != b) && (a->firstName == b->firstname)`.  It does not matter whether the *contents* of `a->firstName` and `b->firstname` match, because you are comparing the *addresses* of their first elements.

You could conceivably use `memcmp()` instead of `strcmp()` to perform the comparison, provided that you don't mind comparing the data *after* any string terminator, too.  But maybe that would be cheating.

If you cannot use any library function then you'll need to compare `char` by `char`, with a loop.  For example,

```
_Bool equal = 0;

for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
    if (a->firstName[i] != b->firstName[i]) {
       // unequal
       break;
    }

    if (a->firstName[i] == '\0') {
        // b->firstName[i] == '\0' too, else control would not reach this point
        equal = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

That assumes properly terminated strings.  If that's not a safe assumption then you can add a limit on `i` in the termination condition of the loop.

Comment: Re “… provided that you don't mind comparing the data after any string terminator, too”: That cannot work. If the strings are different, it will correctly return “unequal”. But, if the strings are equal and not filling the entire arrays, it will return “unequal” if any byte after the null terminator differs, and that is not desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it is unclear what the OP desires, and the context is also unclear.  If, for example, they can rely on the arrays being zero-filled past the end of the strings, or if the array contents are not meant to be compared as strings in the first place, then `memcmp()` would be viable.  This is why I presented the proviso.  The OP must evaluate whether their usage is consistent with that.